# uwp: how to edit a datagrid item in a form control

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been looking through all the microsoft docs related to grids in UWP, but so far I can't see an example of a basic scenario of being able to click on an item and editing it in a form. All the examples I see are of either editing and validating inline, or using the open source version of telerik rad controls which I would much rather stay away from. Can anyone please point me to an example of how to do this? Ideally it would be something like a responsive Master-Detail page, except that the Detail form is editable.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you could refer Windows Community Toolkit [DataGrid Sample](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DataGrid/DataGridCode.bind#L8). And it allow edit item with click. 
[image]

And you could get [Windows Community Toolkit sample app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) from windows store.

Comment: the example you linked to shows inline editing. I am talking about clicking an item and have a form in a dialog or a flyover to edit it.

Comment: You could add DataGrid item click event then show a dialog with item data.